# Data Comparison between SAP Hana and SQL Server

Tags: hash, azure-sql-database, checksum, hana, azure-synapse

I am working on a solution to compare Datasets from SAP HANA and Azure SQL Server to check consistency of data on SQL server.
Instead of getting all the fields from HANA and doing an "except",
I was thinking of evaluating and comparing a Checksum or Hashbytes on both systems.

However, the Hashvalues for same data is not matching.

***Hash Values on SAP HANA***
SELECT HASH_MD5(MANDT), HASH_SHA256(MANDT) from SLT_DECO100.MSKU where CHARG = 'UK2031RP' and WERKS = 'U72D'

0x25DAAD3D9E60B45043A70C4AB7D3B1C6
0x47DC540C94CEB704A23875C11273E16BB0B8A87AED84DE911F2133568115F254

***Hash Values on SQL Server***
select HASHBYTES('MD5', MANDT), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', MANDT)
from consolidation.MSKU where CHARG = 'UK2031RP' and WERKS = 'U72D'

0xA4DC01E53D7E318EAB12E235758CFDC5
0x04BC92299F034949057D131F2290667DE4F97E016262874BA9703B1A72AE712A

Need support to understand and perform comparison

Answer (score 1):

- The **hash values** could be different based on `algorithms` what we are using.
- Here in the below link `comparing` the data from two different environments of same `tables` by providing the pipe delimiters in query.
- The `pipe delimiters` will separates the data from column to column then it gives the accurate results.

Check here for [Compare Records Using Hash Values](https://www.johnxiong.com/2018/01/04/t-sql-compare-records-using-hash-values/).

**Note:** More information for the below text in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks),

- Algorithms (**MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA & SHA1**) are deprecated starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x).
- Use **SHA2_256** or **SHA2_512** instead. Older algorithms will continue working, but they will raise a deprecation event.

Comment: @RajkumarPalnatu-MT, As you can see i am using MD5 hashing algo,
turns out the datatypes on HANA and SQL DB were different causing the issue
HANA: varchar(3) SQLDB: varchar (6)